# ConstraintLayout Placeholder is not laying out as expected

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

As I try to write the layout according to the article [ConstraintLayout Placeholder](https://androidkt.com/constraintlayout) preview the page on the screen is not shown as I expect. What I only changed was to replace the ImageButton with Button. As you can see, Button A's text is not laying out as center_vertical as I expected which I define in the styles.xml.

Is there anyone who can explain the reason, and tell me how to fix it?

thank you.

Here is my layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.PlaceHolderExampleActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/top_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Placeholder
        android:id="@+id/template_main_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        app:content="@+id/top_image"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Placeholder
        android:id="@+id/template_action"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:background="#3F51B5"
        app:content="@+id/A"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/template_main_image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/template_main_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/template_main_image" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/A"
        style="@style/text_style"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="A"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/B"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is style.xml

```
 <style name="text_style">
        <item name="android:background">#E91E63</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>
```

Here is the preview image:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not expect what you are seeing. It appears that the gravity of the button is being ignored when it is part of the *Placeholder*. (Gravity is something of an odd beast anyway.) This looks like a bug to me. If you are so inclined, you might want to consider reporting it in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com). (That is, if you agree.)

In the meantime, here is a workaround that is not too involved. Wrap you button in a *FrameLayout* something like the following. You will need to reference the *FrameLayout* in the *Placeholder* instead of the button.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameForA"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/A"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="A"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

The *FrameLayout* is pretty lightweight. The layout looks like this on an emulator with this change made:

[image]

I simplified the button's definition for this answer. You can, of course, reintroduce your style and reinstate anything else I changed with respect to the button.